# Incorrect redirect after commenting

Tags: functions, comments, redirect

I noticed not too long ago that after posting a comment the user is redirected to a page with this url

```
http://twwr.alexismejias.com/situations/athome/tocome/?author=&email=&location=&comment=&submit=Submit&comment_post_ID=8&comment_parent=0&recaptcha_challenge_field=03AHJ_VuvDbmyP7Fmp8Noq3DoqrQX6yddkVFOz9wqVJxs4saFGsgtvnC9Dd7TmxwYEBxGH9L-YnJQGfNPqbXvVxrHuCeLi4LOTOTNKGDsdobvj0C-jY_jPb4A-F2r7dEHSQLFYWz8S4qScqhplBFWILLXKVmX8Qe_SZw&recaptcha_response_field=
```

Not sure what went wrong but I am assuming that it has something to to with my [functions.php](http://pastebin.com/UgPB1YFE) or [comments.php](http://pastebin.com/AhKRZXpg)

this is my .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /twwr/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /twwr/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
 php_flag display_errors on
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it looks like a problem being caused by the ReCAPTCHA plugin. Have you tried turning that plugin off?

CAPTCHAs are generally ineffective for comments anyway. They prevent spam to some degree, but they prevent real-people even more, and are terrible for accessibility.

A better way to fight spam is to use plugins that don't require human inputs. I personally use a combination of [Simple Trackback Validation](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-trackback-validation/), [Cookies for Comments](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cookies-for-comments/), and [Akismet](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/akismet/). These work great and don't block real-people as well as spambots.

Comment: I have tried disabling it but it still doesn't work. And the site is not for me and the client wants a captcha, although I will bring up your arguments in the next meeting